# Flutter Shared Preferences saving values, not displaying

Tags: sharedpreferences, flutter

I have a list of courses. The user marks each course complete using a checkbox on the ListTile. 
I implemented Shared Preferences so the list of completed courses persists when the user closes the app.
The values are saving, but when the app is closed (in the emulator or through the IDE) and reopened, the UI shows the value as false (Even when the Terminal says the value is True).
When I hot restart, the UI shows the value as True (Which was expected from the start). I haven't been able to get the UI to show correctly using the emulator buttons or on a device.

How can I get the UI to show the values correctly right away?

```
 SharedPreferences prefs;

  void getResult(Course course) async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    results[course.courseResult] = prefs.getBool(course.courseResult) ?? false;
    print('${course.courseTitle} Result: ${results[course.courseResult]}');
    setState(() {
      results[course.courseResult];
      });
  }

  Future<bool> setResult(Course course) async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print ('${course.courseTitle} SET TO ${results[course.courseResult]}');
    return prefs.setBool(course.courseResult, results[course.courseResult]);
  }

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getResult(widget.entry);
    }

  Future onChanged(bool value, Course course)  {
    setState(() {
      results[course.courseResult] = value;
    });
    return setResult(course);
  }
```

Here is the full code (Though I did shorten the lists for space purposes, and left out the pages that aren't affected by this error...)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'CourseList.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';



class LearningPlan extends StatefulWidget{
  LearningPlanState createState() => new LearningPlanState();
}

class LearningPlanState extends State<LearningPlan> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(
        title: Text('Learning Plan'),
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
              new CourseTile(courseList[index]),
          itemCount: courseList.length,
        ),
    );
  }
}

class CourseTile extends StatefulWidget {
  CourseTile(this.entry);
  final Course entry;
  CourseTileState createState() => new CourseTileState();
}

class CourseTileState extends State<CourseTile> {

//Detail Card

  Future<Null> _launched; // ignore: unused_field

  Future<Null> _launchInWebViewOrVC(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false, forceWebView: false);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  Widget selfDirectedURL(Course course) {
    if (course.courseMethod == 'Self-Directed') {
      return new IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_download),
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            _launched = _launchInWebViewOrVC(course.courseURL);
          }),
      );
    } else {
      return new Container();
    }
  }

  Future<Null> courseDetails(Course course) async {
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new SimpleDialog(
          title: Text(course.courseTitle),
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(child: Image.asset(course.courseImage,
                  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.lighten,
                  color: fkBlue25,
                  height: 200.0,
                ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(course.courseDescription),
                ),

              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                selfDirectedURL(course),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('OK'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

//CheckBox Constructors


  SharedPreferences prefs;

  void getResult(Course course) async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    results[course.courseResult] = prefs.getBool(course.courseResult) ?? false;
    print('${course.courseTitle} Result: ${results[course.courseResult]}');
    setState(() {
      results[course.courseResult];
      });
  }

  Future<bool> setResult(Course course) async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print ('${course.courseTitle} SET TO ${results[course.courseResult]}');
    return prefs.setBool(course.courseResult, results[course.courseResult]);
  }

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getResult(widget.entry);
    }

  Future onChanged(bool value, Course course)  async {
    final result = await setResult(course);
    setState(() {
      results[course.courseResult] = value;
    });
    return result;
  }


//Main Tile

  Widget buildTiles(Course course) {
    return Card(
        shape: Border.all(
          color: fkBlue,
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        elevation: 8.0,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(course.courseTitle),
            subtitle: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(course.courseCode),
                Text(course.courseMethod)
              ],
            ),
            leading: SizedBox(
                height: 60.0,
                width: 60.0,
                child: Image.asset(course.courseImage)),
            trailing: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(results[course.courseResult] ? 'Complete' : 'Incomplete',
            ),
                Checkbox(
                  value: results[course.courseResult],
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    onChanged(value, course);
                    if (value == true) {
                      snackBarCompleted(course);
                    } else {
                      snackBarUnCompleted(course);
                    }
                  },
                ),
            ]
          ),
            onTap: () {
              courseDetails(course);
            }
        ),),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildTiles(widget.entry);
  }

  void snackBarCompleted(course) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(
          '${course.courseTitle} completed on ${DateFormat.yMd().format(DateTime.now()).toString()}'
      ),
        backgroundColor: fkBlue,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      ),
    );
  }

  void snackBarUnCompleted(course) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('${course.courseTitle} no longer marked \"Complete\"'
      ),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      ),
    );
  }
}


//Learning Schedule Page

class LearningSchedule extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(
        title: Text('Schedule'),
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
        new LearningScheduleBuilder(courseList[index]),
        itemCount: courseList.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LearningScheduleBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  LearningScheduleBuilder(this.entry);
  final Course entry;

  Widget buildList (Course course) {
    return Text(course.courseTitle,
      style: new TextStyle(color: results[course.courseResult] ? Colors.grey : fkBlue),);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildList(entry);
  }
}

final List<Course> courseList = <Course>[
  new Course(
    courseTitle: 'Company Orientation',
    coursePreReq: 'N/A',
    courseCode: 'HR',
    courseURL: '',
    courseMethod: 'Facilitator-Led',
    courseImage: 'assets/courseImage/logo.png',
    courseDescription:
        'Company overview; Benefits package and documents; Ethics and Compliance Training, Introduction to learning programs; Computer orientation; Lab tour; Safety training.',
    courseAudience: 'BCAE BCCC ITAE ITCC TCTAE TCTCC PlasmaCC PlasmaAE',
    courseResult: 'result1',
  ),
  new Course(
    courseTitle: 'Intro to Learning Program',
    coursePreReq: 'N/A',
    courseCode: 'Nicole Asma',
    courseURL: '',
    courseMethod: 'Facilitator-Led',
    courseImage: 'assets/courseImage/logo.png',
    courseDescription:
        'Overview of onboarding program; Components of North America University; Support available for all learning units; introduction to Learning and Development Team Overview of WebEx calls.',
    courseAudience: 'BCAE BCCC ITAE ITCC TCTAE TCTCC PlasmaCC PlasmaAE',
    courseResult: 'result2',
  ),


class Course {
  final String courseTitle;
  final String coursePreReq;
  final String courseCode;
  final String courseDescription;
  final String courseImage;
  final String courseMethod;
  final String courseURL;
  final String courseAudience;
  final String courseResult;

  const Course({
    this.courseTitle,
    this.coursePreReq,
    this.courseCode,
    this.courseDescription,
    this.courseImage,
    this.courseMethod,
    this.courseURL,
    this.courseAudience,
    this.courseResult,
  });

  Course.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : courseTitle = map['courseTitle'],
        coursePreReq = map['coursePreReq'],
        courseCode = map['courseCode'],
        courseDescription = map['courseDescription'],
        courseImage = map['roocourseImagem'],
        courseMethod = map['courseMethod'],
        courseURL = map['courseURL'],
        courseAudience = map['courseAudience'],
        courseResult = map['courseResult'];
}

Map results = {
  'result1': false,
  'result2': false,
  'result3': false,
  'result4': false,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you make this little change? :

Change this :

```
        Future onChanged(bool value, Course course)  {
            setState(() {
              results[course.courseResult] = value;
            });
            return setResult(course);
          }
```

To this:

```
        Future onChanged(bool value, Course course) async {
            final result = await setResult(course);
            setState(() {
              results[course.courseResult] = value;
            });
            return result;
          }
```

**UPDATE**

Replace your `initState` method with this:

```
          _onLayoutDone(_){
                getResult(widget.entry);
          }


           @override
          void initState() {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_onLayoutDone);
            super.initState();
          }
```

Comment: I did, same result (Pun intended). only way to show the true bool value in UI is to hot restart.

Comment: maybe you could paste all of your code to check the error

Comment: I put in most of the code...The list of courses is 30-something long, so I just put in 2 as examples, for readability. I also didn't put in the other pages that have nothing to do with shared prefs or the course list.

Comment: That did make the UI show correctly initially, but now the initial bool value appears to be the opposite of what is shown?

On Startup: All as expected.
I/flutter (30162): Company Orientation Result: false
I/flutter (30162): Intro to Learning Program Result: true
I/flutter (30162): Home Office Set Up Result: false
I/flutter (30162): Welcome Packet Result: false
I/flutter (30162): Terms and Definitions Result: false

When user clicks the checkbox for Company Orientation
I/flutter (30162): Company Orientation SET TO false

Should be set to true. UI shows as true...

Comment: looks like it's related to your logic , if my answer works for you, please mark as solved and create another question.